# How do I do create or replace editing on a nested object with spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, destructuring, spread-syntax

For simple spreading we can do a create or replace like so:

```js
let a = {1: "one", 2: "two"}; 
let b= {...a, ...{2: "too", 3: "three"}}
console.log(b); //{1: "one", 2: "too", 3: "three"}
```

What I want to do is, is something similar, but on a nested object:

```js
let a = {
   title: "hello world", 
   nestedObject: {
      1: "one", 
      2: "two", 
   }
}; 

let b= {...a, ...{nestedObject: {2: "too", 3: "three"}}};
console.log(b); //Replaces the nested object entirely.
```

What I actually want as a result is:

```
{
   title: "hello world", 
   nestedObject: {
      1: "one", 
      2: "too",
      3: "three" 
   }
};
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: `{...a, ...{2: "too", 3: "three"}}` makes no sense. You'd use `{...a, 2: "too", 3: "three"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this pattern in Redux reducers a lot. This is how I do it:

```
let a = {
   title: "hello world", 
   nestedObject: {
      1: "one", 
      2: "two", 
   }
}; 

let b = {
    ...a,
    nestedObject: {
        ...a.nestedObject, 
        2: "too",
        3: "three"
    }
};
console.log(b); //Replaces the nested object entirely.
```

Note that I now use `nestedObject` as just a property name, and set it to a new object, which starts with `...a.nestedObject`.

So, this means:

- Add everything from `a`
- Override `nestedObject` with a new object (because it comes AFTER `...a`)
- In the new object, add everything from `a.nestedObject`
- Then add (and override any existing) props in `nestedObject` by props coming AFTER `...a.nestedObject`

If you are looking for something that would override any property automatically at any level, there are a few light NPM packages like [deep-assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-assign). It works the same as `assign` but recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Use your nested object from the original object. And only spread that property

```js
let a = {
   title: "hello world", 
   nestedObject: {
      1: "one", 
      2: "two", 
   }
}; 

let b= {...a, nestedObject: {...a.nestedObject, ...{2: "too", 3: "three"}}};
console.log(b); //Will not Replace the nested object entirely.
```

Comment: Though, there's no destructuring either in the question nor in this answer, only spreading. There's also no need for a third nested object, feel free to just list the updated properties.